# Need to transfer the Firebase data to MySQL and synchronize

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an Android project and in our app, we are going to store the abstract user data and we are creating in Firebase because of its feature of real-time updating. But for doing data analysis we need to store the data in some database, for doing the query operation we have thought of MySQL but on searching regarding my query I have found it can be done but it requires NodeJS support on the server which is not provided by our hosting provider. Is there some other way to handle this problem?